# Retrieving intermediate nodes with variable length relationship in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm using the variable length relationship feature in a cypher query, and it seems to be mostly working. However I want to include the intermediate node(s) if any in the results and I can't figure out how to best achieve this.

A simplified example is a query like this

```
MATCH (a:MOL)-[:F2EDGE*1..2]-(b:MOL) RETURN a,b LIMIT 100
```

The a and b nodes are retrieved as expected and in a few cases they are connected where the path length is 1. But in most cases they are disconnected because the intermediate node (path length 2) is not included in the results. The 2 hop query would look like this:

```
MATCH (a:MOL)-[:F2EDGE]-(i:F2)-[:F2EDGE]-(b:MOL) RETURN a,i,b LIMIT 100
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You have to define a path and return it like that :

`MATCH p=(a:MOL)-[:F2EDGE*1..2]-(b:MOL) RETURN p LIMIT 100`